# Azure Synapse, Azure Analysis Serivces and Power BI

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-synapse

Could someone clarify to me if Azure Analysis Service is still an architecture component that we have to consider if we decide to adopt Azure Synapse as DWH environment ?

The question comes in oder to understand if there is some best practise in plase in order to interconnect Power BI with Synapse avoiding to maintain another layer (e.g. Analysis Services).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The feature set isn't 100% identical, but at a high level a Power BI Dataset = AAS database. They use the same engine, so you only need to maintain a separate AAS instance if there is a feature currently available in AAS not currently implemented in Power BI.

Comment: Thanks! I recently discovered two relevant evaluation connected with costs and number of refresh allowed per day. Currently Power BI premium obliged to import data at most 48/day - but with an aggressive licence costs.